# Removable singularity of a function that has real part bounded by $\ln$|$ z - a $|

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

The following question is from the book *Complex Variables* written by Levinson and Redheffer. It is the question 8.7 in additional problems in Chapter 3.

Let $f$ be a complex function that is analytic in $\Omega - \{\alpha\}$, where $\Omega$ is a region, and has a isolated singularity $\alpha$. If Re$f(z) \leq -m\ln$|$ z - \alpha $| for any $z \in \Omega - \{\alpha\}$, show that the singularity is removable.

I am trying to prove that $f$ is uniformly bounded in $\Omega - \{\alpha\}$ by showing that |$e^{f(z)}$| is bounded. However, I can only show that |$e^{f(z)}$|$\leq $|$\frac{1}{|z - \alpha|^m}$ but the right hand side is not bounded as $z$ approach $\alpha$.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may assume that $m$ is a positive integer. We shall work completely in small disk $D$ around $\alpha$. There is a holomorphic function $h$ such that $(z-\alpha)^{m} e^{f(z)}=h(z)$. We  can write $h(z)=(z-\alpha)^{k} \phi (z)$ where $\phi$ is holomorphic with no zeros in smaller disk $D'$ and $k \geq 0$.   We can write $\phi(z) =e^{\psi(z)}$ in $D'$ for some holomorphic function $\psi$.  We now get $(z-\alpha)^{m} e^{f(z)}=(z-\alpha)^{k} e^{\psi(z)}$. Now Consider a small circle $|z-\alpha| =r$ contained in $D'$. On this circle $(z-\alpha )^{m-k}$ has a continuous logarithm. As is well known this implies that $m=k$. Thus $e^{f(z)}=e^{\psi(z)}$. It is now easy to conclude that $f$ has a removable singularity at $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Kabo. Do you mind explain how you know $\phi(z)$ is in the form of $e^{\psi(z)}$ and why knowing $(z - \alpha)^{m-k}$ has a continuous logarithm can imply that $m = k$. I have not read these parts in my book yet.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya In any open disk (more generally in any simply connected region) any analytic function with no zeros can be written as $e^{\phi (z)}$ with $\psi$ analytic. The function $z-\alpha)^{k}$ does not have  a continuous logarithm in any full circle around $\alpha$ unless $k=0$ This is a basic property of logarithms in the complex plane.

Comment: I just finished that part and understand your proof now. May I ask you one more question? Within the proof of existence of analytic logarithm, given an analytic function $f(z)$ that has no zeros in the domain $D$, another function $g(z)$ is defined by $g(z) = \int^{z}_{z_0} \frac{f^{'}(\xi)}{f(\xi)} d\xi  +  ln f(z_0)$ where $z_0$ is a fixed number and the integral is taken along a $z$ - $z_0$ path. In this case, how to show that the derivative of $e^{g(z)} f(z)$ is always 0? .

Comment: @SanaeKochiya The fact that $ \frac {g(z+h)-g(z)} h=\int_z^{z+h} \frac {f'} f$ (where the integral is again over a line segment) requires Cauchy's Theorem. (The integral over the triangle formed by $z_0,z,z+h$ is $0$). Once this is done you can use the same argument as in real variables to find the derivative of $g$  and use product rule t0 differentiate $e^{g(z)f(z)}$.

Comment: I got what you mean. I just recalled that if $f$ is analytic in the domain $f'$ will be as well and that could show that $\frac{f'}{f}$ is analytic in the domain. Thank you for your hints. Just to point out a typo. What I wrote is $f(z) e^{g(z)}$ instead of $e^{f(z)g(z)}$.